# Google Play prominent disclosure not found

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-console

I have already made numerous attempts, but still cannot get through the app review. The app always gets rejected for the following reason:

> Prominent disclosure not found

Your app must display a prominent disclosure through a pop-up alert before your app’s location runtime permission. Based on our review, a prominent disclosure did not appear before the runtime permission.

In my opinion, which is based on [this](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9799150?hl=en#zippy=%2Csee-an-example-of-prominent-in-app-disclosure%2Cstep-provide-prominent-in-app-disclosure) article, the app fulfills the requirements and does exactly the same as the demo app in the article.

When the app starts for the first time, the user is guided through the app intro in which the needed permissions are explained and requested:

1. [I explain the user why the app needs the permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlJb2.png)
2. When the user presses on the forward button, a [popup window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ak3io.png) shows up (I did this because I thought it might get the app through the review by adding a additional disclosure)
3. When the user presses the forward button again, the [location permission gets requested](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z24pR.png)

The same procedure happens for the [background location permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Pcr2.png).

I don't really understand why the app gets rejected... It's really frustrating because there is no detailed explanation and appealing the review results in the exact same rejection reason.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coming back to this a few month later to post an answer in case some other people have the same issue...

In my case I forgot to update the walk through video which you need to provide when accessing sensitive permissions.
I made some changes in order to comply with Googles requirements and resubmitted the App. The reviewer then probably just watched the old video and based on that, decided that the app still doesn't fulfill the requirements.

Never had any rejected updates since then!

Comment: Thanks for coming Back :).. I have the Same issue. My app is rejected 19 times and shouting **** for the last rejections... I didn't know that they look at the video. I can enter a Youtube URL at the Store settings but I thought that was only for "promotion" purposes. Or do I miss something and is there another video URL to be set?

Comment: I found it... If you have sensitive permission you have to add a video showing the feature that needs that sensitive feature. You can add that details and youtube link here: https://play.google.com/console/u/0/developers/app/app-content/permission-declarations

Now in My case, only 1 specific build in the closed testing track had background locations permission. Though another release was rolled out to production, the reviewer still looks at that closed testing release. Pausing the track didnt work, I made a new release in Closed testing.

Comment: It's work on my case too, I have fix prominent disclosure issue but the app keep rejected 7 times! I have do appeal on rejection, but reply from support not helped & they like not try the app (just watch the video explanation). After update the  video about explanation service of accessibility, the update get accepted & live. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: im going to try updating my video and see if it finally goes through. I've been struggling with this for 16 releases so far. Thanks for documenting how you got past it